# Sens de « qu'est-ce que » dans deux contextes particuliers

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, questions, locutions

**I** contexte de l'usage avec certains verbes intransitifs ou pronominaux

- Qu'est-ce que tu restes là à bayer aux corneilles ?
- Qu'est-ce que tu te mêles de cette affaire quand tu n'y a aucun intérêt ?
- Qu'est-ce que vous insistez quand on vous dit qu'il est parti ?

**II** contexte de l'usage avec certains verbes transitifs

- Qu'est-ce que tu m'apportes des cerises à Pâques ? C'est le temps des œufs en chocolat !
- Qu'est-ce que tu mets des chemises à fleurs à quatre-vingts ans ?
- Vous aussi … qu'est-ce que vous le regardez de travers quand vous savez qu'il est irritable ?

Quel sens donner à cette expression dans ces cas inhabituels ? Existe-t-il une interprétation utile pour tous les contextes ? Doit-t-on plutôt tenir compte du contexte dans chaque cas ? Le ton de ces pseudo-questions est toujours apparemment  celui du reproche ; connait-on d'autres usages pour lesquels un ton différent conviendrait ?

ADDITION du 25 mai 2019

Les exemples fournis ci-dessus sont des exemples personnels constitués de mémoire et ils sont représentatifs d'un usage moderne ; la recherche effectuée par user **survenant9r7**, dont le produit est les exemples ci-dessous, montre qu'il s'agit d'un usage qui, s'il ne relève pas de la langue soutenue, a néanmoins laissé son empreinte dans la littérature.

- *Qu'est-ce que tu avais besoin, aussi, d'aller chercher une fille aux bois* ; (Aymé)

des ex. où le sens de « pourquoi » tend à s'estomper (selon LBU)

- *Qu'est-ce que tu me regardes ?* (Salacrou)
- *Qu'est-ce que cela vous regarde ou vous intéresse ?* (Claudel)
- *Qu'est-ce que ça pourrait lui servir, un prêtre ?* (Veuillot)
- *Qu'est-ce que tu parles de voler ?* (Harpagon dans « L'avare» de Molière)
- *Qu'est-ce que c'est donc que vous me regardez toute effarée ?* (La Comtesse dans « La Comtesse d'Escarbagnas » de Molière)

Comment: Une petite correction; on dit "bayer aux corneilles" et non "bailler aux corneilles".

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Personnellement, je ne les aime pas trop et ne cherche pas à les utiliser mais on les entend. Je voulais savoir s'il n'y aurait pas eu quelque chose de plus à comprendre, mis à par l'idée globale d'un  pourquoi.

Comment: Par hasard j'ai trouvé des exemples au LBU14 §402d+R3 : _Qu'est-ce que tu avais besoin, aussi, d'aller chercher une fille aux bois_ (Aymé) ; et des ex. où le sens de pourquoi tend à s'estomper dit le LBU : _Qu'est-ce que tu me regardes ?_ (Salacrou) ;  _Qu'est-ce que cela vous regarde ou vous intéresse ?_ (Claudel) ; _Qu'est-ce que ça pourrait lui servir, un prêtre ?_ (Veuillot) ; _Qu'est-ce que tu parles de voler ?_ ; _Qu'est-ce que c'est donc que vous me regardez toute effarée ?_ (Molière)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Très bon travail ! Il serait intéressant de pouvoir considérer tout cela ailleurs que dans des commentaires ; ça constitue une  justification de taille pour ma question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wasn't familiar with these two contexts using "qu'est-ce que" to form pseudo-questions (with actual question marks) of the abusive variety (as distinguished from rhetorical ones), I would agree that the tone of all of your examples is one of reproach, for they all seem to be questions masquerading as reproachful assertions.
  (I'm certainly familiar with using "qu'est-ce que" to add emphasis to positive, complementary assertions [e.g., "Qu'est-ce que t'es belle/beau!//"Qu'est-ce que tu parles bien!], but these are not questions and therefore don't fit your examples and don't answer the final, *ton différent*, part of your question as I understand it.)

---

Regarding "*Quel sens donner à*//*ininterprétation utile pour* ... *cette expression?*" (but only in "abusive/reproachful pseudo-questions" contexts) the following suggestion, **somewhat** similar to the construction at issue, would go beyond the simple notion of "*pourquoi*," which is perhaps too neutral to help one (at least me, a non-native speaker) fully understand and accurately interpret the reproachful tone intended in such contexts:

> [**Qu'est-ce qui t'a pris de**](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/qu%27est-ce+qui+t%27a+pris+de) ... rester là ...//...  te mêler
>   ...//... vous insister...//...  m'apporter...//... mettre...//...  le
>   regarder ... .  (some *Reverso/Context* examples at the link)

Comment: I share this point a view : the basic idea, raising a concern as to the why of whatever is being questioned, is not central and there is something else, not conveyed by the "tag" (qu'est-ce que), which is after all deprived of much meaning here, but by the tone, the attitude of the speaker; in certain cases, there is hardly the possibility of a why : "Qu'est-ce que vous me parlez de présidents avant 1700, il n'y a jamais eu que des rois jusque là!." This particular case could be rendered by more than one idea I think, for instance,  "Je ne comprends pas, êtes-vous fou ?" (champ 1)

Comment: (puzzlement) and then this new case that occurred to me tends to confirm that the why is but an  accessory notion. That way of speaking would seem to be a regressive way, in which the words aren't used to carry the meaning but instead open the road to a variety of meanings left to be expressed by whatever chosen attitude of the speaker : a real economy of words but more incertitude. (end)

Answer (score 7):

L'expression "Qu'est-ce que", dans tous ces contextes-là, a le sens de "pourquoi" mais indique surtout la surprise et l'irritation du locuteur, ou la consternation.

Pour ce qui est des raisons de ce glissement, je passerai à la spéculation : je le perçois comme la frustration du locuteur menant à un empêtrement de la parole et, du coup, à un usage à contre-emploi de "qu'est-ce que" au lieu de "pourquoi" ; ou alors, à une abréviation de formulations comme "Qu'est-ce que tu **fais à** rester là ?" en "Qu'est-ce que tu restes là ?"

On retrouve le même genre de formation avec "d'où", qui est utilisé dans le même genre de situation (par exemple, "d'où, tu mets des chemises à fleurs à quatre-vingts ans ?" -- pour "d'où", c'est souvent suivi d'une pause dans le cas de cet usage donc je le transcris suivi d'une virgule, mais ce n'est pas le cas pour "qu'est-ce que" dans les exemples mentionnés dans la question).

Cet usage de "qu'est-ce que" et de "d'où" est de registre familier, voire pourrait être perçu par certains comme une faute.

Comment: Dans les deux cas, ce sont des expressions exclusivement orales et plutôt familières.

Comment: @Pierre merci, ajouté

Comment: «  je le perçois comme la frustration du locuteur menant à un empêtrement de la parole et, du coup, à un usage à contre-emploi de "qu'est-ce que" au lieu de "pourquoi"  » : je conçois bien cela  aussi mais hypothétiquement, dans les phases initiales de son introduction dans la langue ; c'est une tournure qui m'a toujours semblé avoir, lorsque j'ai eu l'occasion d'y être confronté, la qualité de quelque chose de bien systématique (pas d'hésitation, ton ferme).